# Output a string a design time

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, design-time

I have the following code that runs at design time in my WPF app:

```
applicationDirectory = (from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                        where assembly.CodeBase.EndsWith(".exe")
                        select System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
                                    assembly.CodeBase.Replace("file:///", ""))
                               ).FirstOrDefault();
```

I would like to see what that is actually returning at design time.

Is there a way to do that?

**Note:** I tried Debug.Write(applicationDirectory); and I did not see anything in the output window.
**Note II:** I am not asking what the value of `applicationDirectory` will be, I am asking for a mechanism to see the value (so I can use it elsewhere too).

Answer (score 0):

You could return the path as a property on a view model and bind that to a control in the UI.  Works for me.